# desplazamiento de un objeto en game maker

Tags: game-maker

al ejecutar el codigo en el evento create en game maker studio 2:

```
sprite_index = Spr_Pacman_Right; //imagen del sprite pacman

image_speed = 0;//velocidad de imagen

image_index = 0;//indice de la imagen

 v = 0; // variable de velocidad
```

todo bien pero al ejecutar el codigo del evento step:

```
if (keyboard_check(vk_right)){
direction = 0;
speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_left)){
direction = 180;
speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_up)){
direction = 90;
speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_down)){
direction = 270;
speed = v;
}
```

el objeto en pantalla no se mueve

Answer (score 1):

Es porque debes indicarle en que eje quieres que el personaje avance, si quieres que avance a la derecha indícale que sume el valor de la variable v (velocidad) al eje X, por ejemplo:

```
if (keyboard_check(vk_right)){
direction = 0;
x += v; // moverse a la derecha
}
```

en el caso de la izquierda es lo mismo, pero restando a X

```
if (keyboard_check(vk_left)){
direction = 180;
x -= v;
}
```

Para arriba y abajo debes trabajar el eje Y

```
if (keyboard_check(vk_up)){
direction = 90;
y += v // moverse abajo
}
```

Por ultimo, si a "v" le das un valor de 0, no pasará nada; debe ser 1 o más.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

no se mueve por que te olvidaste en el evento create la variable de instancia `v = 0;` y si le dices que la velocidad es v `speed = v;` entonces le estas diciendo que la velocidad es cero.
ahora en el arreglo solo asignale una valor distinto a la variable `v =`si es para pacman en una room de 64x64 te recomiendo que la velocidad sea múltiplo de 2, por ejemplo `v = 4`

quedaría así:

```
sprite_index = Spr_Pacman_Right; //imagen del sprite pacman

image_speed = 0;//velocidad de la animación de la imagen

image_index = 0;//indice de subimagen

v = 4; // **variable de instancia creada para la velocidad**
```

todo bien pero al ejecutar el codigo del evento step:

```
if (keyboard_check(vk_right))
{
    direction = 0;
    speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_left))
{
    direction = 180;
    speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_up))
{
    direction = 90;
    speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_down))
{
    direction = 270;
    speed = v;
}
```

para la animación de la imagen

```
//Animacion

if speed > 0
{
     image_speed = 8;
}
else
{
     image_speed = 0;
     image_index = 0;
}
```

si aun así no se mueve, ve al EDITOR DE SPRITE
-se abre dando doble click en los sprite
- revisa la mascara de colisión en el editor de sprite al lado izquierdo de la ventana y en modo lo pones a imagen completa.
- al centro de la ventana revisa que todos los objetos tengan en la casilla que dice Origen (0)(0) y por defecto este en superior izquierda

eso seria todo y ya deberia moverse de forma correcta

Answer (score -1):

Tienes dos errores:

1. En `CREATE` la variable `V` no puede ser cero, se esperaba `>0` Asignale
   un numero a la variable.

   ```
   V=5; //Aquí se especifica la velocidad.
   ```
2. Te falta un código en el evento `STEP`;

EL código sería este: `speed=0` colocalo al principio del `step` de esta forma:

```
speed=0

if (keyboard_check(vk_right)){
direction = 0;
speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_left)){
direction = 180;
speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_up)){
direction = 90;
speed = v;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_down)){
direction = 270;
speed = v;
}
```